# How to convert a particular column in table from hex to decimal in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query of 15 columns and one of them has a hexadecimal value, i wanted to convert it to decimal or int. How can i do it

Comment: Post the sample value.

Comment: Connected Devices
0
16
0
1
9
13
9
000c
000b
5
9
000c
000b
000a
000a
0
9

Comment: Thank you. Now post the expected result.

Comment: so wherever it is a it should be 10, wherever it is b it should be 11 and wherever it is c it should be 12 and so on...

Comment: expected result is  0
16
0
1
9
13
9
12
11
5
9
12
11
10
10
0
9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, *rowName*) AS Converted *rowName*;
```

EDIT:
CONVERT works with MS SQL

CONV(num, base, to) is for MySQL

`SELECT CONV(*rowName*,16,10) AS Converted *rowName*;`

Comment: This throws an error..are you sure INT should be used

Comment: error is there is mistake as the value are getting converted to 0

Comment: Usually works for me unless MS SQL has a slightly different SYNTAX || EDIT 1: Sorry You need to use `CONV(rowName , 16 , 10 );`

Apologies MySQL Uses a few different identifiers

Answer (score 0):

use `CONV()`

```
 CONV(num , from_base , to_base );

select SELECT CONV('b',16,10)'Hexadecimal to Decimal'
```